# php codeigniter array undefined offset error

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, offset

i am using codeigniter, and i am declaring a variable array, i used the array and it worked fine, but php keep showing some error that does't affect the program. anyone know what's happen ??
this is my code :

view :

```
<?php
$banyak = 0;
$id = $results->id;
$barangNama = $results->nama;
$barangHarga = $results->harga;
$barangGambar = $results->gambar; //resulting string "1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg"

$s = 0;
//declare variable array
$newGambar = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($barangGambar); $i++) {
    if ($barangGambar[$i] == ',') {
        $s++;
    } else {
        /* here is line 90 */ $newGambar[$s] .= $barangGambar[$i];
    }
}

print_r($newGambar);
?>

<?php
$w = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $s; $i++) {


    if ($w % 4 == 0) {
        $banyak++;
    }
    $w++;
    echo $banyak;
    ?>
    <div class="item <?php if ($i == 0) {
        echo "active";
    } ?>" data-thumb="<?php echo $banyak - 1; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/product_picture/<?php echo $newGambar[$i]; ?>">
    </div>

    <?php
}
?>
```

what i want to achieve is divided $barangGambar each coma, 
and input to 
$newGambar[0] = 1.jpg
$newGambar[1] = 2.jpg and so on

but i have to loop to decide how many picture that provided

this is error msg :

> ```
>     A PHP Error was encountered
>     Severity: Notice
>     Message: Undefined offset: 0
>    Filename: webView/webProductZoomed.php
>    Line Number: 90
> ```

Answer (score 1):

remove . from this line and remove `$s` from array index

```
$newGambar[] = $barangGambar[$i];
```

Comment: i am trying to insert a string there, please read the code again

Answer (score 1):

You're doing something strange here:

```
$newGambar[$s] .= $barangGambar[$i];
```

Maybe you meant: `$newGambar[] = $barangGambar[$i];` ?

There's no need for a counter here, since every element added to the array will automatically receive an incremented index, so you'll still end up with
`$newGambar => array (0 => 'element1', 1 => 'element2')` and so on

Comment: what i mean is $newGambar[$s] = $newGambar[$s] . $barangGambar[$i]; it is same as $newGambar[$s] .= $barangGambar[$i];

Comment: lets just i asking this, if i want to take a string seperated by coma, and input every string into an array and insert to different index each, am i doing it right ?

Answer (score 1):

You wish to separate the string by comma and store the filenames in a new array? ie. turn `"1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg"` into `array("1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg")` ?

Replace:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($barangGambar); $i++) {
    if ($barangGambar[$i] == ',') {
        $s++;
    } else {
        /* here is line 90 */ $newGambar[$s] .= $barangGambar[$i];
    }
}
```

with:

```
$newGambar = explode(',',$barangGambar);
```

[`explode`](http://php.net/explode) will split a string by the delimiter (in this case the comma `,`) and store each part in the resulting array.

As for why undefined offset error:

During the first loop `$newGamber[0]` equals null (does not exist). As such attempting to concatenate onto it will return an undefined offset error. It is only a value has been placed into `$newGamber[0]` the error will stop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your question but this'll work for you

```
$barangGambar = "1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg";

if(!empty($barangGambar)){
    $newGambar = explode(',',$barangGambar);
}

print_r($newGambar);
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/377407)

Comment: And if there's another possibilities of string than post it within your question too..